# Django forms HTML5 validate pattern

Tags: python, django, html, forms, validation

Dugen Chen wrote a helpful post on adding the 'required' attribute in HTML5's validation to Django form fields.
http://duganchen.ca/elegantly-adding-html5-validation-attributes-to-django-form-fields/

I would also like to have the HTML5 pattern attribute automatically included so that if this is my form:

```
class AccountEditForm(forms.Form):
  email = forms.EmailField()
  phone = forms.CharField(widget=forms.IntegerField)
```

Then the following html will be created:

```
<input type="email" name="email" id="id_email" required pattern="-email regex-" />
<input type="text" name="phone" id="id_phone" required pattern="-integer regex-" />
```

Dugen used this method:

```
compose = lambda f, g: lambda *args, \
          **kwargs: f(g(*args, **kwargs))

def html5_required(field):
  if field.required != False:
    field.widget.attrs['required'] = 'required'
  return field

CharField = compose(html5_required, CharField)
```

so that a forms could still be written like

```
class SampleForm(form):
  text_field = CharField()
```

and the 'required' attribute would be added appropriately

Could someone explain how to do something similar with for the pattern attribute.
Could all this be applied with a decorator so this mess could reside somewhere else?

Ideally, is there a set of regex patterns standardized to match each Django form field and has anyone built a small library to easily add it into Django?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Two options come to mind, here.  You may either create a mixin that updates all fields on the class, or monkeypatch the standard library.

To monkeypatch, you would do something like:

```
from django.forms import fields
fields.__dict__.update({
    name: compose(html5_required, field)
    for name, field in fields.__dict__.iteritems()
    if issubclass(field.__class__, fields.Field)
})
```

The mixin approach would basically do the same thing, but by iterating over the attributes involve some meta programming magic and redefine them if necessary.  General concepts are [outline here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-pymeta/index.html).